# Does enabling Fast Boot have any effects on an Ubuntu installation?

Tags: uefi, windows-8, bios, microsoft

I'm not running a dual boot system, just Ubuntu on an old laptop that had Windows on it, I've noticed Fast Boot enables in BIOS (UEFI), does it do any harm if I keep it enabled and run Ubuntu only?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can sometime cause conflicts where the underlying Windows structure has "grabbed" control of certain aspects but where UEFI is present on a PC using Linux exclusively, in particular ubuntu, UEFI has good support. Refer to [this article](https://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/) for more information.

If windows is present in a dual boot environment,best to make sure that Windows is fully closed down and there are two methods for doing so:

- Simply hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and then click `Shut down`
  option in the `Start` menu;
- Perform a full shut down using the command prompt [image]

[reference](https://www.top-password.com/blog/fully-shutdown-windows-10-instead-of-hibernating-it/)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but what if I'm not running Windows at all? I only have Ubuntu on that device, does it still have any effects?

Comment: without windows at all ubuntu supports UEFI - you can see how this affects you in [this article](https://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: I've amended my answer to reflect the additional information, You may wish to accept it if it answers your question. Thanks